# if df_2 is a subset of df_1 - how to remove df_2 values from df_1?

Tags: r

I have a dataframe, `df_2` which is a subset of `df_1`:

```
df_2 <- df_1[ lots_of_conditions, ]
```

I would now like to create a new dataframe `df_3` which is `df_1` with all the `df_2` records removed.

```
df_3 <- ???
```

**Question**: how is this done in R?

Comment: I expect this question to already have an answer, I did search for duplicated questions but couldn't find anything that looked the same as what I am asking.

Comment: what about `df_1[!lots_of_conditions, ]` ?

Comment: @CathG there are too many conditions, so it will be error prone to negate them all and convert `&`s to `|`s.

Comment: I posted an answer to develop my comment : once you know how to create df_2 (the conditions you need), creating df_3 doesn't require any thinking... ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To develop what I was saying in my comments, you can create `df_3` with the exact same information you use to create `df_2` :

Let's say your conditions for `df_2` are as follows :

```
lots_of_conditions <- cond1 & cond2 & (cond3 | cond4)
```

So, you do `df_2 <- df_1[ lots_of_conditions, ]` to get `df_2` and you can just do

```
df_3 <- df_1[!lots_of_conditions, ]
```

to get df_3.

Doing this, you just negate the conditions used to create df_2 without the trouble of explicitly negate them (changing `|` in `&` etc. ).

Answer (score 2):

Since you are dealing with `data.frame`s, you should be able to use:

```
df_1[!rownames(df_1) %in% rownames(df_2), ]
```

Note, however, that this won't work with, say, a `data.table`, where there are no row names.

---

Something like the following might also work:

```
df_2$FLAG <- TRUE
df_2$FLAG <- ""
Combined <- merge(df_1, df_2, all = TRUE)
Combined[is.na(Combined$FLAG), ]
```

(But the best/fastest/most reliable thing would be to keep an index of what you are subsetting, so you can use `!lots_of_conditions` as suggested by @CathG).